# How to add more user gender options in mediawiki user preferences?

Tags: mediawiki, wikimedia

On special:preferences mediawiki users are given a choice between two genders. For my wiki I'd like to add more options. For example: 'transgendered', or 'none of your damn business'. Is this doable?

Answer (score 1):

No, because it makes no sense. MediaWiki only deals with grammatical gender. If your language has multiple grammatical genders which could/should be used for users in the interface, more than the currently supported male/female/generic, please [tell us](https://translatewiki.net/wiki/Talk:Gender) because we've never heard of any such language (there's someone requesting neuter gender for bots and so, though).

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. All the method described below was done working with Mediawiki 1.17.0.

I'm asumming you're authenticated at least as a sysop of the wiki and that you have full access to the FTP folder and are able to modify the wiki files.

You will need to modify the ***/includes/Preferences.php*** file.
Go around line 200 and you'll find the following code:

```
$defaultPreferences['gender'] = array(
'type' => 'select',
'section' => 'personal/info',
'options' => array(
    wfMsg( 'gender-male' ) => 'male',
    wfMsg( 'gender-female' ) => 'female',
    wfMsg( 'gender-unknown' ) => 'unknown',
),
'label-message' => 'yourgender',
'help-message' => 'prefs-help-gender',
);
```

Add the new genders you'll need:

```
$defaultPreferences['gender'] = array(
'type' => 'select',
'section' => 'personal/info',
'options' => array(
    wfMsg( 'gender-male' ) => 'male',
    wfMsg( 'gender-female' ) => 'female',
    wfMsg( 'gender-transgender' ) => 'transgender',
    wfMsg( 'gender-noneofyourbusiness' ) => 'noneofyourbusiness',
),
'label-message' => 'yourgender',
'help-message' => 'prefs-help-gender',
);
```

Finally, you'll need to go to the ***MediaWiki:gender-transgender*** and ***MediaWiki:gender-noneofyourbusiness*** (assumming you added those two new genders) pages of your wiki and edit them with the text you'd like to see when selecting a gender option.

That should be all. Enjoy!